# %s set correctly but PyMySQL still complaining about %d

Tags: python, pymysql

I am new to Python and am trying to create a form that will save the data to a DB via PyMySQL, but I'm having an issue connecting to the DB. I have followed  an example code (my version is below) and checked all syntax and speech marks thoroughly but am still getting the following error.

```
File "c:\Users\Nimrod\Nimrod Dropbox\Dropbox\Nimrodsky\Python\Adiabatic Equation\DB connect with PyMySQL.py", line 10, in <module> charset='utf8')
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\__init__.py", line 90, in Connect return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 706, in __init__ self.connect()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 922, in connect self.host_info = "socket %s:%d" % (self.host, self.port)
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

---

```
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='sql8.freesqldatabase.com', 
                            port='3306', 
                            user='********', 
                            password='**********', 
                            db='*********',
                            charset='utf8')


try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Create a new record
        sql = "INSERT INTO `client` (`ID`, `client_name`, `client_address_1`, `client_address_2`, `client_address_3`, `client_postcode`, `occupier_name`, `install_address_1`, `install_address_2`, `install_address_3`, `install_postcode`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('1', 'Terry Jones', '10 DOwning Street', 'Guildford','Surrey', 'GU1 5HA', 'Paul Smith', 'Wimbledon Hill', 'Wimbledon', 'London', 'SW19 5QT'))

    #connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save
    #your changes.
    connection.commit()

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Read a single record
        sql = "SELECT `id`, `occupier_name` FROM `client` WHERE `client_name`=%s"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('Terry Jones',))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        print (result)

finally:
    connection.close
```

Answer (score 5):

Port must be an integer: `port=3306`.

Comment: Thanks for that phd, rather a stupid mistake on my behalf, considering that PyMySQL opens port 3306 by default and if I had left the offending line out then I think that the code would have worked. Thanks again and take care.

Comment: I wish pymysql could give a better error message, thus preventing people from feeling like they did something stupid when really it was a pretty reasonable misunderstanding.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck In the world of free software you could be a coauthor. Send a patch or a pull request.